# how thread lock handle subsequent function call sequence

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, locking, mutex

how exactly thread locks handle the sequence of the messages/function calls that arrive while the locked block is still active?

i have read about high level programming models (e.g. C#.Net, Java) as well as low level programming models (e.g. C, Assembly) so i usually think in bytes as the basis for all my questions and thus it is giving me a lot of headache whenever i try to find the answers to my questions.

in multi threading, one of my fundamental confusion is that how does locking affect the messages or function calls that arrive later after the block has been locked or has already been used by a particular process.

does the OS handle these messages sequence? does the OS provide an internal queue or storage to store sequentially the messages corresponding to the sequence that they arrive?

i hope you can enlighten me on this one.

Below is the sample program in C#.Net Console App for simplicity:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace MultiThread
{
    class Program
    {
        static object padlock = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                string s = "hello " + i.ToString();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SayHello, s);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void SayHello(object message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.ToString() + " start");
            lock (padlock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message.ToString() + " running");
                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    {
                        string[] f = File.ReadAllLines("bigfile.txt");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                Console.WriteLine(message.ToString() + " finish");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(message.ToString() + " end");
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Question :

1. Notice the "hello i start" sequence is 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. The threads are not started sequentially based on the loop sequence. why?
2. The "Hello i start" is located outside the lock so here we can say that this part of code can be accessed by multiple threads but the "Hello i running" is located inside the lock so only one thread can enter a process at a time. The "hello i running" sequence is 0, 1, 5, 8, 7, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9. I would expect that the "running" sequence would be the same as the "starting" sequence if the threads come in FIFO but in this case, the running sequence is quite different or don't follow a certain sequence compared to the loop sequence or the starting sequence.

Highlight: The "Hello i start" shows the arrival of the message/function calls. The "Hello i running" shows the sequence of the threads running at single time.

Comment: It's not clear what you ask about. A particular example, e.g. some pseudo-code that illustrates your questions, might be of help.

Comment: hi @AlexeyKukanov , I have edited the question to show the pseudocode and the results.